# Equivalente en javascript para printf de C

Tags: javascript

Algo que me sucede muy a menudo es necesitar formatear un string para ello termino concatenando de manera manual varias cadenas, mi pregunta es si hay alguna implementación de [printf](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) en javascript

para el que no conosca que hace `printf`

```
printf("Color %s, numero1 %d, numero2 %05d, hex %x, real %5.2f.\n", "rojo", 12345, 89, 255, 3.14);
```

devolvería:

```
Color rojo, numero1 12345, numero2 00089, hex ff, real 3.14.
```

**Actualización**

De momento comento que encontré una solución parecida pero no exacta al problema.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var formatted = this;
    for( var idx in arguments) {
    formatted = formatted.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + idx + "\\}", 'g'),  arguments[idx]);
    }
    return formatted;
};
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
"hola usuario de {1}, hoy es {0}".format('viernes', 'Stack Overflow ES')
```

Comment: exactamente que solución quieres? si quieres darle formato a los numeros tendras que probar algunas librerias como [Numerla.js](http://numeraljs.com/) pero no tendras exactamente algo como un printf a menos que tu lo hagas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final buscando encontre esta libreria [sprintf](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) que hace lo que necesitaba. muchas gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score 2):

Desde ES6 javascript soporta interpolación de cadenas algo parecido a printf en c++

```
var cadena = "Adios Mundo";
console.log(`${cadena}`);
```

nótese que deben usarse el acento grave " ` " en lugar de comillas simples o dobles